# .Net 5 functions apps Service bus topic trigger with Json data is not working

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5, azure-servicebus-topics

We are developing our functions apps on .net 5 for Service Bus Topic Trigger functions.

To test that I am sending messages to Service bus Topic from the Azure portal.

I am not getting the Application/Json content-type data(complex object) to the function app trigger and working for simple objects like string(Text/Plain).

Can any one help on this.

```
[Function("ServiceBusFunction")]
[ServiceBusOutput("outputQueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string item,
    FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger("ServiceBusFunction");

        logger.LogInformation(item);

        var message = $"Output message created at {DateTime.Now}";
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Isolated Worker SDK? You can only receive primitive types. Also, when asking a code related question, post some code you're using.

Comment: Hi @sean .I am not able to post my code here right now .but my code is very similar to the code I have updated. Instead of queues I am using topic trigger there and in the parameters I have my custom object Message from Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Comment: You can deserialize the incoming message that is received Nas a string `item`. And the outgoing string should be a serialized object, a valid JSON string. What you're sending is not JSON. Have a look at my post here: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages

Comment: Still there is a confusion. I am sending messages from the client application similar to what mentioned in this link .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

Comment: I am sending the messages to Service bus from the client app and expecting to receive that through the function app service bus topic trigger .But in your code I am seeing you are preparing message in function app itself. Please correct if my understanding is wrong

Comment: For your information I am using ServiceBusMessage in Client all to send the messages with some user properties

Comment: You cannot receive `ServiceBusMessage` type, only primitive types such as `string` and `byte[]`. Sorry mate, I don't understand your problem. Post a link to reproduction on GitHub perhaps?

Comment: @Aditya Can you update your question to include your expected behavior ? As Sean mentioned above, you will not be able to use `ServiceBusMessage` type. What type are you trying to bind and failing. Include the that information in the question. Also please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a class which represents the JSON data you are sending **as the message body** of your service bus message and use that class as a parameter of your azure function which listens to service bus events. When a new message is posted in the portal (to the service bus queue), the functions framework will bind that JSON data to an instance of this type.

For example, If you are sending the below JSON using the [Service bus explorer feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/explorer) in azure portal while setting the **Content Type** value as `Application/Json`,

```
{
    "OrderId": "202110",
    "Total": 25.61,
    "Customer": {
        "Id": 782,
        "Type": "Premium"
    }
}
```

Create a class which represents the above data.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use the `Order` type as your function parameter type.

```
[Function("ServiceBusFunction")]
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("replyTo", Connection = "MyServiceBusConn")] Order order, 
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var logger = context.GetLogger("ServiceBusFunction");
    logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {order}");
}
```

When a message arrives, the `Order` instance will be populated from the JSON data you sent. The same solution will work if your sending code is sending a valid JSON string as the [body of the service bus message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusMessage__ctor_System_String_). So if you want to send a complex object, serialize that object to a JSON string and use that as the body of the message.

Keep in mind that you can only use a type which represents the [message body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-dotnet#properties). You cannot use the `ServiceBusMessage` from `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`(*which is a wrapper class with the Body along with other meta properties of the message*) as the parameter type.

Screen shots from a working demo of this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is working if I hit it the service bus from the Azure portal as mentioned in the above screenshots with the custom entity as a function app parameter. But I am sending a message to Service bus from the API using TopicClient which sends the Message (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus). Do I need the prepare the replica of Message entity class in my function app?

Comment: You can serialize your custom object and send that as the body of the ServiceBusMessage instance using [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusMessage__ctor_System_String_). Yes, you need a type defined in your function app which matches your JSON String structure (the type you use in your client app to create the serialized string)